# Creating Connection Pool and using the connection pool in JanusGraph

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3, janusgraph, gremlin-server

I am using JanusGraph. How do I create a connection pool while connecting to JanusGraph remotely and then using the pool to borrow the connection?

right now I am doing something like

```
private static void init() {
        String uri = "localhost";
        int poolSize = 5;

        graph = JanusGraphFactory.open("inmemory");
        cluster = Cluster.build()
                .addContactPoint(uri)
                .port(8182)
                .serializer(new GryoMessageSerializerV1d0(GryoMapper.build().addRegistry(JanusGraphIoRegistry.getInstance())))
                .maxConnectionPoolSize(poolSize)
                .minConnectionPoolSize(poolSize)
                .create();
        gts = graph
                .traversal()
                .withRemote(DriverRemoteConnection.using(cluster));
    }
```

this init method is initialized once. and then anyone who requires connection simple calls the below method

```
public GraphTraversalSource getConnection() {
        return gts.clone();
    }
```

Please note that withRemote() method is being deprecated now. I am not sure am I doing it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're confusing some concepts. You only need to use the TinkerPop driver (i.e. `Cluster`) if you are connecting to a `Graph` instance remotely. In your case you're creating your JanusGraph instance locally, so you can simply do `graph.traversal()` and start writing Gremlin. If you hosted your JanusGraph instance in Gremlin Server on the other hand, then you would need to use the `withRemote()` option. As you mention `withRemote()` in the fashion you are calling it is deprecated, but the [javadoc](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/current/full/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/process/traversal/dsl/graph/GraphTraversalSource.html#withRemote-Configuration-) mentions the new method which can also be found in the [documentation](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#_connecting):

```
import static org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.AnonymousTraversalSource.traversal;
GraphTraversalSource g = traversal().withRemote(DriverRemoteConnection.using(cluster));
```

To understand all the different options for connecting to a `Graph` instance I'd suggest reading [this section](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#connecting-gremlin) of TinkerPop's Reference Documentation.

Comment: using AnonymousTraversalSource.traversal throws an error that java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Graph does not support transactions. Is any workaround available?

Comment: that is expected. there are no transactions with remote traversals. a transaction is bound to a single request or said another way, your entire traversal effectively encompasses a single transaction. Gremlin Server will automatically commit/rollback as needed.

Comment: Also, the key point is to keep only one GraphTravelSource as singleton object. Earlier I was closing GraphTraversalSource after each query. This was hindering the use of connection thread pool which is tied with GraphTraversalSource